# Python3: Decode UTF-8 bytes converted as string

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8, decode, encode

Suppose I have something like:

```
a = "Gżegżółka"
a = bytes(a, 'utf-8')
a = str(a)
```

which returns string in form:

```
b'G\xc5\xbceg\xc5\xbc\xc3\xb3\xc5\x82ka'
```

Now it's send as simple string (I get it as assertion from `eval` function). How the heck can I now get normal UTF-8 form of starting word? If there is some better compression than `str(bytes(x))` then I would be glad to hear.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "I get it as assertion from `eval` function", but that sounds like you're doing something that's a very bad idea in code right outside the code that you showed us…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to encode and decode text, that's what the [`encode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) and [`decode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) methods are for:

```
>>> a = "Gżegżółka"
>>> b = a.encode('utf-8')
>>> b
b'G\xc5\xbceg\xc5\xbc\xc3\xb3\xc5\x82ka'
>>> c = b.decode('utf-8')
>>> c
'Gżegżółka'
```

Also, notice that UTF-8 is already the default, so you can just do this:

```
>>> b = a.encode()
>>> c = b.decode()
```

The only reason you need to specify arguments is:

- You need to use some other encoding instead of UTF-8,
- You need to specify a specific error handler, like `'surrogatereplace'` instead of `'strict'`, or
- Your code has to run in Python 3.0-3.1 (which almost nobody used).

---

However, if you really want to, you *can* do what you were already doing; you just need to explicitly specify the encoding in the `str` call, just as you did in the `bytes` call:

```
>>> a = "Gżegżółka"
>>> b = bytes(a, 'utf-8')
>>> b
b'G\xc5\xbceg\xc5\xbc\xc3\xb3\xc5\x82ka'
>>> c = str(b, 'utf-8')
>>> c
```

Calling `str` on a `bytes` object without an encoding, as you were doing, doesn't decode it, and doesn't raise an exception like calling `bytes` on a `str` without an encoding, because the main job of `str` is to give you a string representation of the object—and the best string representation of a `bytes` object is that `b'…'`.

Answer (score 0):

I found it. The simplest way to convert string representation of bytes to bytes again is through the `eval` statement:

```
a = "Gżegżółka"
a = bytes(a, 'utf-8')
a = str(a) #this is the input we deal with

a = eval(a) #that's how we transform a into bytes
a = str(a, 'utf-8') #...and now we convert it into string

print(a)
```

Comment: As @abarnert commented it looks like you are trying to fix the wrong code but if you are going to do this at least use `ast.literal_eval` instaed of `eval`.

Comment: Welp, now I found that I just load script without utf-8 encoding. But still, I think that trying to decipher str(bytes(x)) is interesting problem :)

Comment: I don't know what you are talking about, there is nothing like that in your question. As you found out you can reconstruct a bytes object from its string representation but you cannot do that with arbitrary objects so I would say a more interesting problem is how you managed to paint yourself into that corner and how to avoid it.