# How to convert the string representation of a binary string froma text file back into the utf8 encoded text it came from?

Tags: python, string, encoding, utf-8

I have a word in russian: "привет".
It is encoded into utf-8 bytes using
`'привет'.encode('utf-8')`
the result is python bytes object represented as:

```
b'\xd0\xbf\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82'
```

Now I saved it inside a file and when I read that file I get this string:
`"b'\\xd0\\xbf\\xd1\\x80\\xd0\\xb8\\xd0\\xb2\\xd0\\xb5\\xd1\\x82'"`

How do I decode this string into the original word?

It is not the bytes object I'm trying to decode but a string, so

```
"b'\\xd0\\xbf\\xd1\\x80\\xd0\\xb8\\xd0\\xb2\\xd0\\xb5\\xd1\\x82'".decode('utf-8')
```

returns `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`

The way I save it to a file is simply by calling `logger.info(x.encode('utf-8'))` which is

```
import logging 
logger = logging.getLogger('GENERATOR_DYNAMICS')
```

and the way I read a file is

```
with open('file.log') as f:
    logs = f.readlines()
```

Comment: 1st hin on duckduckgo with `python decode byte string utf8` was the dupe - you did not really search a lot, did you? Please read [ask]  - first line of duty is doing research. (not my dv btw)

Comment: @PatrickArtner is it not the byte object to decode that is the problem, I'm trying to decode a string

Comment: maybe you could [edit] your post and show how you write to the file, how you read from the file and whats the exact problem with it.  If you write (binary) into a file and read (binary) from a file you get the (binary) values back.

Comment: if you write the _stringrepresentation_ of you bytearray into a textfile, you need to get it into a bytearray again:  `import ast` + `print("b'\\xd0\\xbf\\xd1\\x80\\xd0\\xb8\\xd0\\xb2\\xd0\\xb5\\xd1\\x82'", 
      ast.literal_eval("b'\\xd0\\xbf\\xd1\\x80\\xd0\\xb8\\xd0\\xb2\\xd0\\xb5\\xd1\\x82'"
).decode("utf8"))
`

Comment: @PatrickArtner thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Edited, upvoted and answered with a community answer - feel free to accept it if you like, points go nowhere :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problems are two fold:

- you got the *stringrepresentation* of a bytearray (from a file, but thats kindof irrelevant)
- you want to get the bytearray back to utf8 text

So the solution is two steps as well:

```
import ast

# convert string representation back into binary
string_rep = "b'\\xd0\\xbf\\xd1\\x80\\xd0\\xb8\\xd0\\xb2\\xd0\\xb5\\xd1\\x82'"
as_binary = ast.literal_eval(string_rep)

# convert binary to utf8
text = as_binary.decode("utf8")
```

to get `'привет'` again.

The last part is a duplicate of [Python3: Decode UTF-8 bytes converted as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51200908/python3-decode-utf-8-bytes-converted-as-string)